# Idiomatic way to represent DB entity in code shared between client and server

Tags: database, scala, slick, shapeless, scala.js

Let's say I have a RDBMS table `persons` with name column (`String`) and age column (`Int`). This could perfectly fit into `case class Person(name: String, age: String)` if we wouldn't need an id in server-side. Problem is that in some cases we have id, like when we get person from DB (backend), but sometimes we haven't, like when we create person in form (frontend).

Three simplest possible ways I see:

- Create different classes `FrontendPerson` and `BackendPerson` with conversion. Very boilerplate, no direct connection
- Add wrapper `DbItem(id: Long, person: Person)`
- Add `id: Option[Long]`. Very boilerplate too, in most cases we know that `id` is available and therefore `Option#get` will propagate.

I'm wondering if there's some better (probably more generic, with shapeless) or integrated into doobie ways.

Comment: There is a video that discusses this exact problem in scala: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xSfLPD6tiQ

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick using default parameters:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, id: Long = 0L)
```

Because the `id` column is there at the end of the case class, and has a default value, you can effectively ignore it.  E.g., you can create instances of it ommitting `id`.

This only really makes sense if:

- the `id` is an autoinc column in the database, so you never have to manage it yourself.
- instances of `Person` are pulled from the database, so the `id` field will be populated for anyone who cares to use it.

It addresses most of your concerns. But... +1 to @triggerNZ's link to the tpolcat presentation on a principled way to attack this.